# Press enter for maintenance (or type control-d to continue)

Tags: server

I am using windows 10 and configured Ubuntu on virtual machine using Hyper-V for making a shared file server within our small office. I have assigned 2048Mb RAM to Ubuntu file server. I am facing a problem, whenever the physical computer shuts down accidentally (Due to electricity issue) and restarts, the file server is not accessible. When I open the Hyper-V, Ubuntu gives the message in last line

```
Welcome to emergency mode! After logging in, type "journalct1 -xb" to view
Press enter for maintenance (or press Control-D to continue"
```

[image]

The only problem is that I have to manually RDP the server and click manually the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to continue otherwise it keeps there and server files are not accessible.

I am not very good in Linux and just first time I am using it with the help of video tutorials.
Kindly help me out to get rid of this situation so in any case when the physical computer restarts, the VM starts completely itself.
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should actually run `journalctl -xb` for once and see what is failing.

Comment: Maybe you should put this ubuntu server on dedicated machine or cloud VPS.

Comment: Getting this error when trying to execute journalctl -xb

Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system.
  Users in the 'systemd-journal' group can see all messages. Pass -q to
  turn off this notice.
No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your file-system is corrupted. Try this:

First identify your partition.

Run the command:

> umount -t /dev/**your-partition**

Then:

> fsck -y /dev/**your-partition**

For example, my Linux `/` directory is at `sda3`, but my `/home` directory is at `sda5`, so when something like this happens to me, I do the following:

- Press enter for command line;
- Type:

> umount -t /dev/sda3

- Hit enter;

> umount -t /dev/sda5

*****DO NOT USE: umount -a*****

- Hit enter;
- Then:

> fsck -y /dev/sda3

- Hit enter;

> fsck -y /dev/sda5

- Hit enter;

*If you don't know which partition to choose, type `umount -t /dev/sd` and hit  <kbd>tab</kbd> twice for you to see its available partitions.*

Comment: After pulling out a disk, I hit this problem. Ubuntu 22.04 can't boot into the normal mode. It was NOT clear to me why it did not. The error was probably buried in the 9239 lines of `journalctl -xb` 's output; since pulling out the disk was the only change I made, I commented the disk's line at /etc/fstab, saved, and entered `exit` on the command line. Then it entered the login screen. Everything is normal now.